# How to understand s the virtual to physical translation?

Tags: linux, kernel

the codes is:

```
include/asm-x86/page_32.h

#define __pa(x) ((unsigned long)(x)-PAGE_OFFSET)
#define __va(x) ((void *)((unsigned long)(x)+PAGE_OFFSET))
```

How to understand the __pa(x) ?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whole address space is divided to User space and Kernel space. In x86 ratio of user-to-kernel space is usually 3:1. This means that lower 3GiB is used for user space, and the upper 1GiB is for kernel. This ratio can be changed when configuring the kernel. 
Now the `PAGE_OFFSET` macro indicates the beginning of the kernel address space, in x86 with default 3:1 user-to-kernel ratio it's value is `0xC000000`. 
First region of kernel address space is used for mapping (direct mapping) page frames to virtual address space, and this regions spans from `PAGE_OFFSET` to `high_memory` 
The `high_memory` is used when system has more than 896MiB of memory. 
Memory region that can be mapped directly is called `normal`, and pages that cannot are in `highmem`